# how to fix error, the procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library PhysX3CharacterKinematic_x64.dll

Tags: dll

I install Hitman YearEdition v 1.13.1 game. when I want to run it this error appears.

> the procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link
>   library PhysX3CharacterKinematic_x64.dll

all files are downloaded and exist in the directory.
I don't know how to fix it. please help me.

**System Info:**

- Radeon Software Version - 17.11.1
- Graphics Chipset - **Radeon RX 560 Series**
- Windows Version - **Windows 10 (64 bit)**
- Memory Size - 4096 MB
- Memory Type - GDDR5
- System Memory - 16 GB
- CPU Type - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6600 CPU @ 3.30GHz
- DirectX-12 Applyed

[image: Error Image]

[image: Directory Files]

Comment: You could try checking both the _.exe_ and the _.dll_ with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com).

Comment: thanks, @CristiFati